# How does the generalized Haldane statistics give rise to the admissible configurations of fractional quantum Hall ground states?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-hall-effect

It's often stated in fractional quantum Hall and fractional Chern insulator literature (see for example, [*Phys. Rev. X* **1**, 021014 (2011)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevX.1.021014) and [arXiv:1308.0343](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0343)) that ground states of fractional quantum Hall states and similarly their lattice analogues known as fractional Chern insulators have certain allowed configurations when expanded in the orbital bases (orbitals could be a component of the angular momentum or momentum in one direction). For example, a Laughlin state at filling  $ \nu = 1/m $ follows what is known as $(1,m)$ admissible rule meaning that there is only one filled orbital every $m$ consecutive orbitals. For $\nu = 1/3$, this gives us configurations like $$\dots 1001001001001\dots$$
This is often justified based on the generalized Haldane exclusion principle (derived here [*Phys. Rev. Lett.* **67**, 937 (1991)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.67.937)) that generalizes Pauli exclusion principle to particles with fractional statistics. In the paper, Haldane defines (equation 2) the statistical interaction $g_{\alpha \beta}$ as how the Hilbert space  dimension of a single particle of type $\alpha$ changes when particles are added or removed to the system, $$ \Delta d_\alpha = - \sum_{\beta} g_{\alpha \beta} \Delta N_{\beta} $$ For quasi-particles and quasi-holes at filling $\nu = 1/m$, Haldane derived $g_{\alpha \pm} = \mp \frac{1}{m}$ with $\alpha = \pm $. The $+$ is for quasi-particles and $-$ is for quasi-holes.

My question is, given the value of the statistical interaction of quasi-holes and quasi-particles, how can we derive the rules that restrict the occupation in the Fock space of orbitals for the ground state given that we know that it has those quasi-holes and quasi-particles excitations? I cannot understand yet if such connection exists or not and if so, how to understand it?

Any help is appreciated!